# Cesium-terrain-builder-docker error when i load cesium.js in browser

Tags: cesiumjs, terrain

I want to serve custom terrain data at my server, so I tried Cesium Terrain Builder Docker ([cesium-terrain-builder-docker](https://github.com/tum-gis/cesium-terrain-builder-docker)).

(maybe) Completely generate quantized-mesh-terrain using cesium-terrain-builder docker, but error occurs when loading cesium.js in browser

Generated quantized-mesh terrain using cesium-terrain-builder:

[image: Generated quantized-mesh terrain using cesium-terrain-builder]

This is my HTML code:

[image: Minimal HTML code]

and this is error message at Chrome browser console:

[image: error message]

Comment: could you solve your problem ?! If yes, can you share your solution. i have exactly same problem.

Comment: Hi. Sorry i couldn't solve problem. I just using Cesium ion service

Comment: Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1):

Change 
url: 'http://localhost:8080/tilesets/daegu/tiles'
to url: 'http://localhost:8080/tilesets/tiles' in the terrainProvider.

Comment: error occur like this my trying maybe right. there was no get(Not found) error.
GET http://localhost:8080/tilesets/tiles/layer.json 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8080/tilesets/tiles/0/1/0.terrain?v=1.0.0 404 (Not Found)
An error occurred in "w": Failed to obtain terrain tile X: 1 Y: 0 Level: 0.
GET http://localhost:8080/tilesets/tiles/0/0/0.terrain?v=1.0.0 404 (Not Found)
An error occurred in "w": Failed to obtain terrain tile X: 0 Y: 0 Level: 0.

Comment: >>docker pull geodata/cesium-terrain-server
      >>docker run  -d  --name your_terrainserver_name -p 8080:8000 -v Your_Local_Path/tilesets/daegu:/data/tilesets/terrain geodata/cesium-terrain-server

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide some more information on how you serve the tileset?
Are you using a normal web server or a dedicated service for publishing tilesets like
[CesiumTerrainServer](https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-server)?

In general I see two possible sources for this error:

1. Terrain tiles **serving path is wrong**:

   In that case, try opening your `layer.json` file in the browser, e.g. open `https://localhost:8080/tilesets/daegu/tiles/layer.json`. If that fails, you can be pretty sure there is something wrong with the path. Check your path and the documentation of the tileset provider service to fix that. For CesiumTerrainServer this is described [here](https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-server#usage).
2. Tiles are served with **wrong content encoding**:

   This usually only applies if you serve your tiles directly from a web server like Nginx or Apache. Cesium terrain tiles are gzipped and have to be served using `gzip Content-Encoding`. Try adding this header to the web server location you serve the tiles from, e.g. using Nginx:

   ```
   location ~* \.terrain$ {
       add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
   }
   ```

   The full example is available [here](https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-server#usage).

[Here](https://github.com/tum-gis/3dcitydb-docker-compose/tree/cesium-terrain-server/web-map%2Bcesium-terrain-server) is an example on how to use Docker to run CesiumTerrainServer with some documentation, that might be helpful as well.